# How to add a function to excel column with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I w like to find help to solve the following task:
Given a 4 column excel table (A, B, C, D), 
how to add a function to column 5, which is `E1 = B1 * D1`?

I wrote the following code, but not all cells will recover:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx') # output.xlsx have 4 columns
Sheet = wb.active 
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['E'], i):
      cellObj.value = '=$B{i}*$D{i}'
wb.save("o.xlsx")
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not all cells will recover` ? Could you explain how this fails and what the problem it more precisly ? do you miss **f** of f-stirng `f'=$B{i}*$D{i}'` ?

Comment: @azro: I'm _very_ sure `'=$B{i}*$D{i}'` **wasn't** meant to be an f-string — but the OP does need to add some details to their question.

Comment: `enumerate` Starts with `0` but Spreadsheets are `1` based.

Comment: azro and all, I corrected the question : E1 = B1*D1

Answer (score 0):

this code is working:
    `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')`
    `Sheet = wb.active`
    `for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['E'], 1):`
           `cellObj.value = '=$B${0}*$D${0}'.format(i)`
     `wb.save("o.xlsx")`
  but the header (row1 ) is in function, I cant modify to fix for now :(
  ( i = 2 is not work )

Comment: Use `enumerate(Sheet['E'][1:], 2)`